# Collecting the terms of a multi-variable polynomial

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

Suppose I have a polynomial $$P(x,\,y)=a^5+b^2x+c\,y+d\,x^2+e\,x+f^3y+g\,y^2+h\,x^2$$ and I want to collect it in terms of main variables $x,\,y$ to get $$P(x,\,y)=a^5+(b^2+e)x+(c+f^3)y+(d+h)x^2+g\,y^2$$ How do I use `Collect` or similar commands to perform the task?

Input

```
P == a^5 + b^2*x + c*y + d*x^2 + e*x + f^3*y + g*y^2 + h*x^2
```

Output wanted

> ```
> P(x, y) = a^5 + (b^2 + e)*x + (c +f^3)*y + (d + h)*x^2 + g*y^2
> ```

A substantial example

```
 Collect[b^4 m^4 - 2 a^2 b^2 m^2 n^2 + a^4 n^4 - 4 b^3 m^4 R + 
4 a^2 b m^2 n^2 R + 4 a b^2 m^2 n^2 R - 4 a^3 n^4 R + 
4 b^2 m^4 R^2 - 8 a b m^2 n^2 R^2 + 4 a^2 n^4 R^2 + 2 b^2 m^4 S - 
2 a^2 m^2 n^2 S - 2 b^2 m^2 n^2 S + 2 a^2 n^4 S - 4 b m^4 R S + 
4 a m^2 n^2 R S + 4 b m^2 n^2 R S - 4 a n^4 R S + m^4 S^2 - 
2 m^2 n^2 S^2 + n^4 S^2 - 2 b^2 c^2 m^2 T^2 - 2 a^2 c^2 n^2 T^2 + 
4 b c^2 m^2 R T^2 + 4 a c^2 n^2 R T^2 - 2 c^2 m^2 S T^2 - 
2 c^2 n^2 S T^2 + c^4 T^4, {R, S}]
```

results in

```
b^4 m^4 - 2 a^2 b^2 m^2 n^2 + a^4 n^4 + 
(4 b^2 m^4 - 8 a b m^2 n^2 + 4 a^2 n^4) R^2 + 
(m^4 -2 m^2 n^2 + n^4) S^2 - 
2 b^2 c^2 m^2 T^2 - 2 a^2 c^2 n^2 T^2 + c^4 T^4 + 
S (2 b^2 m^4 - 2 a^2 m^2 n^2 - 2 b^2 m^2 n^2 + 2 a^2 n^4 - 
   2 c^2 m^2 T^2 - 2 c^2 n^2 T^2) + 
R ( -4 b^3 m^4 + 4 a^2 b m^2 n^2 + 4 a b^2 m^2 n^2 - 4 a^3 n^4 + 
       (-4 b m^4 + 4 a m^2 n^2 + 4 b m^2 n^2 - 4 a n^4) S + 
    4 b c^2 m^2 T^2 + 4 a c^2 n^2 T^2   )
```

Note several issues:

1) The last term appears as $R (A+BS+C)$ instead of $(A+C)R+BRS$

2) One would expect a standard form, for example $AR^2+BRS+CS^2+DR+ES+F$, for the outcome but the result does not seem to follow a discernible order.

3) The constant term , the one without $R$ or $S$, is split.

Comment: What's wrong with `Collect[P, {x, y}]`?

Comment: @J.M. How do you prevent it from doing partial factorization, as in writing $x(2x+3y)$ instead of $2x^2+3xy$.

Comment: When I evaluate `Collect[a^5 + b^2*x + c*y + d*x^2 + e*x + f^3*y + g*y^2 + h*x^2, {x, y}]`, I get the result you ask for and none of the additional factoring you allude to in your comment.

Comment: Judging by your comment, you have a weak example in that there are no "mixed" terms having factors of both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @MichaelE2 a better example provided

Comment: @m_goldberg an example showing partial factorization is provided

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the third argument of `Collect` to bind the coefficients in something like `Hold`.  Afterwards, release the hold or replace wrapper by `Identity`.

```
ReleaseHold@
 Expand@Collect[poly =
   b^4 m^4 - 2 a^2 b^2 m^2 n^2 + a^4 n^4 - 4 b^3 m^4 R + 
    4 a^2 b m^2 n^2 R + 4 a b^2 m^2 n^2 R - 4 a^3 n^4 R + 
    4 b^2 m^4 R^2 - 8 a b m^2 n^2 R^2 + 4 a^2 n^4 R^2 + 2 b^2 m^4 S - 
    2 a^2 m^2 n^2 S - 2 b^2 m^2 n^2 S + 2 a^2 n^4 S - 4 b m^4 R S + 
    4 a m^2 n^2 R S + 4 b m^2 n^2 R S - 4 a n^4 R S + m^4 S^2 - 
    2 m^2 n^2 S^2 + n^4 S^2 - 2 b^2 c^2 m^2 T^2 - 2 a^2 c^2 n^2 T^2 + 
    4 b c^2 m^2 R T^2 + 4 a c^2 n^2 R T^2 - 2 c^2 m^2 S T^2 - 
    2 c^2 n^2 S T^2 + c^4 T^4,
   {R, S}, Hold]
(*
  b^4 m^4 - 2 a^2 b^2 m^2 n^2 + a^4 n^4 +
   (4 b^2 m^4 - 8 a b m^2 n^2 + 4 a^2 n^4) R^2 +
   (-4 b m^4 + 4 a m^2 n^2 + 4 b m^2 n^2 - 4 a n^4) R S +
   (m^4 - 2 m^2 n^2 + n^4) S^2 -
   2 b^2 c^2 m^2 T^2 - 2 a^2 c^2 n^2 T^2 + c^4 T^4 + 
   S (2 b^2 m^4 - 2 a^2 m^2 n^2 - 2 b^2 m^2 n^2 + 2 a^2 n^4 - 
      2 c^2 m^2 T^2 - 2 c^2 n^2 T^2) + 
   R (-4 b^3 m^4 + 4 a^2 b m^2 n^2 + 4 a b^2 m^2 n^2 - 4 a^3 n^4 + 
      4 b c^2 m^2 T^2 + 4 a c^2 n^2 T^2)
*)
```

Other wrappers can be fun:

```
Expand@Collect[poly, {R, S}, Style[#, Red] &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get a usable expression, execute this:

```
% /. Style -> (# &)
```

`Defer` makes for nice output that can be copied as input without further processing.

```
Expand@Collect[poly, {R, S}, Defer]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You seem to have `n=2` somewhere.  +1

Answer (score 3):

This is your polynomial:

```
p = b^4 m^4 - 2 a^2 b^2 m^2 n^2 + a^4 n^4 - 4 b^3 m^4 R + 
   4 a^2 b m^2 n^2 R + 4 a b^2 m^2 n^2 R - 4 a^3 n^4 R + 
   4 b^2 m^4 R^2 - 8 a b m^2 n^2 R^2 + 4 a^2 n^4 R^2 + 2 b^2 m^4 S - 
   2 a^2 m^2 n^2 S - 2 b^2 m^2 n^2 S + 2 a^2 n^4 S - 4 b m^4 R S + 
   4 a m^2 n^2 R S + 4 b m^2 n^2 R S - 4 a n^4 R S + m^4 S^2 - 
   2 m^2 n^2 S^2 + n^4 S^2 - 2 b^2 c^2 m^2 T^2 - 2 a^2 c^2 n^2 T^2 + 
   4 b c^2 m^2 R T^2 + 4 a c^2 n^2 R T^2 - 2 c^2 m^2 S T^2 - 
   2 c^2 n^2 S T^2 + c^4 T^4;
```

Try this:

```
lst = Drop[Flatten[Table[R^n*S^m, {n, 0, 2}, {m, 0, 2}], 1], 1]

(* {S, S^2, R, R S, R S^2, R^2, R^2 S, R^2 S^2}  *)
```

and then

```
Collect[p, lst]

(*  b^4 m^4 - 2 a^2 b^2 m^2 n^2 + 
 a^4 n^4 + (4 b^2 m^4 - 8 a b m^2 n^2 + 4 a^2 n^4) R^2 + (-4 b m^4 + 
    4 a m^2 n^2 + 4 b m^2 n^2 - 4 a n^4) R S + (m^4 - 2 m^2 n^2 + 
    n^4) S^2 - 2 b^2 c^2 m^2 T^2 - 2 a^2 c^2 n^2 T^2 + c^4 T^4 + 
 S (2 b^2 m^4 - 2 a^2 m^2 n^2 - 2 b^2 m^2 n^2 + 2 a^2 n^4 - 
    2 c^2 m^2 T^2 - 2 c^2 n^2 T^2) + 
 R (-4 b^3 m^4 + 4 a^2 b m^2 n^2 + 4 a b^2 m^2 n^2 - 4 a^3 n^4 + 
    4 b c^2 m^2 T^2 + 4 a c^2 n^2 T^2)  *)
```

**To address your question in the comment**

One may do as follows

```
p1 = p /. {R -> 0, S -> 0};
p2 = p - p1;
Collect[p2, lst] + Simplify[p1]

(* b^4 m^4 + (4 b^2 m^4 - 8 a b m^2 n^2 + 4 a^2 n^4) R^2 + (-4 b m^4 + 
    4 a m^2 n^2 + 4 b m^2 n^2 - 4 a n^4) R S + (m^4 - 2 m^2 n^2 + 
    n^4) S^2 + (a^2 n^2 - c^2 T^2)^2 - 2 b^2 m^2 (a^2 n^2 + c^2 T^2) +
  S (2 b^2 m^4 - 2 a^2 m^2 n^2 - 2 b^2 m^2 n^2 + 2 a^2 n^4 - 
    2 c^2 m^2 T^2 - 2 c^2 n^2 T^2) + 
 R (-4 b^3 m^4 + 4 a^2 b m^2 n^2 + 4 a b^2 m^2 n^2 - 4 a^3 n^4 + 
    4 b c^2 m^2 T^2 + 4 a c^2 n^2 T^2) *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: You can also use patterns `{R, S, S^_, R^_, S*R, S^_*R^_}` for the second argument, and it extends to arbitrary degree.  (I tried this first, but left one or two out, I think, and it didn't work. Instead of finding my error, I thought it didn't. +1)

Comment: It looks like the coefficient of $R^0S^0$, i.e. the constant term, is split into two pieces.

Comment: @Maesumi  Yes, It looks so.

Comment: @Maesumi It's the automatic sorting by `Plus` and a famous difficulty with *Mathematica* and "constant terms."  You can't really avoid it.  In my answer, the terms are wrapped in another function. You have to get rid of the wrapper before you can use the result algebraically, but then the terms get sorted automatically, since `Plus` is `Orderless`.

Comment: There is a way around. Have a look at the edit.